# Facebook friends that have installed my app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to retrieve a list of ids for friends that've installed my apps. I'm currently using this query, but it's returning 0 friends... Why is that?

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                        token,
                        "/"+ facebookUserId +"/friends", response -> {
                            User newUser = new User();

                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                //TODO: Handle error gracefully
                                Log.e("TEST", response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                                return;
                            }

                            try {
                                JSONArray listOfFriendsJson = response.getJSONObject()
                                        .getJSONArray("data");
                                Log.i("TEST", "Found " + listOfFriendsJson.length() + " friends");

                                for (int i=0 ; i < listOfFriendsJson.length() ; i++) {
                                    JSONObject friendJson = listOfFriendsJson.getJSONObject(i);
                                    newUser.friends_list.put(friendJson.getString("id"), true);
                                    Log.i("TEST", friendJson.getString("id"));
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error parsing response of GraphRequest", e);
                                //TODO: Stop loading and show error
                            }

                        });
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that some friends of yours authorized your app with the user_friends permission?

Comment: I tried logging in (pushing the login button in my app) from a friend’s phone who is a friend of mine on Facebook. But it showed 0 friends on both our phones

Comment: and the user_friends permission definitely showed up, and you definitely authorized it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-4-2018

> ...Apps requesting the following permissions are now subject to
>   heightened scrutiny during Login Review:
>
> - ...
> - user_friends
> - ...

I assume that the user_friends permission did not show up in the login dialog for your friend. Try adding your friend as Tester in the App settings and go through the login process again. Make sure you get asked for the `user_friends` permission on both phones.

Comment: Actually I’ve just realized that user_friends is not showing up on my permissions, I think this is the problem right here... Thank you